# I getting error using antd moment.js in react project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, momentjs

I'm using antd date-picker in my react with typescript project.

I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught Type Error: moment is not a function.
```

Please help me for solution

.tsx file::

```
const dateFormat = 'MM-DD-YYYY';

<DatePicker size='small' placeholder='MM-DD-YYYY' defaultValue={moment(, dateFormat)} onChange={onChange} className='pglobaldob'/>
```

Comment: please provide more code, and check if moment is imported or not.

Comment: maybe you don't have moment installed brother. install it from npm

Comment: I have already installed..

Answer (score 1):

You have to install moment,

`npm install --save moment`.

You also need to install the type definition so that the typescript compiler can resolve the types specific to moment.js:

```
npm install @types/moment
```

and then import it like this:

`import * as moment from 'moment';`.

Hoping this will work. Actually iam new to typecripts. :)

Comment: I have already installed..
const [datepicker, setDatepicker] = useState(null);
i'm using antd datepicker. Select date from datepicker and click on search button(or going to other tab and come back) selected date value is still exist(remaining fields cleared). I'm unable to clear or null
if(visible == false && (pglobalname !='' || pglobalmrn != '' || pglobalphone != '' || datepicker != '')){
    setPglobalname('');
    setPglobalmrn('');
    setPglobalphone('');
    setDatepicker('');
  } <DatePicker  onChange={onChange} /> unable to pass value={moment('date',dateFormate)}

Comment: can you please edit your question with more code and also {moment('date').format()} is the correct format